# SSIS: What are some good Beginner SSIS tutorials?

Tags: ssis

I am used to 2000 and recently made the switch to 2008.  If anyone knows of any good tutorials out there besides the msdn ones please let me know thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has really helped me:

[Sql Share](http://www.sqlshare.com/channel.aspx?cat=c871236d-8554-42e3-8683-4d422356c0bd&page=1)

Answer (score 0):

When I was really digging into SSIS, to learn it for a project I was working on, I bought the following book, and found it very helpful.

```
http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Microsoft-Integration-Services-Programmer/dp/0470247959/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1290109078&sr=1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog is useful:
http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-the-introduction/

and there also a good book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Knights-24-Hour-Trainer-Integration-Programmer/dp/0470496924](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470496924)